# C# WPF WebBrowser. Capture JSON API Response

Tags: c#, wpf

Im using the WebBrowser control to load a webpage.

As part of the webpage loading it performs an API Request to a webservice which returns a JSON string.

Is there any way for me to see this raw JSON some way using the WebBrowser control.

In Chrome i can see the Json response using the Developer Tools.

Comment: It this a web page that you have built? Can you call the api with c# code? Can we know some more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: `var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(the url you see in chrome dev window)`

Comment: I take it your request is in javascript that is inside of the webpage? If so then you can just dump that into a html element. Do you use `promise` to get the result?

Comment: @XAMlMAX There is a .js script file in the webpage. The functions within this file get called. How do I load this into a HTML Element?

Comment: `document.getelementbyid();` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) is a link on how to use it.